# Google sheets APIv4 comment data to pandas df, not values

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm getting the notes for ranges `A1:E7` of a sheet. There are notes in `B1`, `E1`, `D4` and `B7`.

```
result = gsheets.service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=key, fields="sheets/data/rowData/values/note").execute()
data=result['sheets'][0]['data'][0]
```

produces the following dictionary:

```
{u'rowData': [
        {u'values': [{}, {u'note': u'B1 notes'}, {}, {}, {u'note': u'E1 notes'}]},
        {}, 
        {}, 
        {u'values': [{}, {}, {}, {u'note': u'D4 notes'}]},
        {}, 
        {}, 
        {u'values': [{}, {u'note': u'B7 notes'}]}
        ]
}
```

Now how do I get this into a 7x5 dataframe that mimics the range A1:E7? I want to use `''` for the blank cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is a bit hard to read, but it works in my tests. The first step is to build a temporary DataFrame from the top-level list of dicts, where each (possibly empty) dict represents a row in the original spreadsheet.

Assuming your dictionary is named `d`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d['rowData']) 
temp
                                                     values
0  [{}, {'note': 'B1 notes'}, {}, {}, {'note': 'E1 notes'}]
1                                                       NaN
2                                                       NaN
3                        [{}, {}, {}, {'note': 'D4 notes'}]
4                                                       NaN
5                                                       NaN
6                                [{}, {'note': 'B7 notes'}]

# JSON-normalize each non-null row
res = (pd.DataFrame(temp['values'].map(lambda x:
                                       json_normalize(x).values.flatten() 
                                       if x is not np.nan else [np.nan]) 
                                  .values
                                  .tolist()
                   )
      ).fillna('')

res.index = range(1, res.shape[0]+1)
res.columns = list('ABCDE')

res
  A         B C         D         E
1    B1 notes              E1 notes
2                                  
3                                  
4                D4 notes          
5                                  
6                                  
7    B7 notes
```